# Merge two PDFs with different page orientations with iText

Tags: pdf, itext

I'm having a problem with merging two different PDFs into one while preserving page sizes and orienations.

There are one PDF (A4) and another one (A4 landscape).
I'm trying to achieve this result

[Result 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ji0gH.jpg)

but I'm still getting this (using PdfSmartCopy or PdfCopy)

[Result 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYDQn.jpg)

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Show us the original PDFs. Show us your code. You should not expect an answer on this question because **the problem you describe can not be reproduced**. This code works perfectly: [How to merge documents correctly?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-merge-documents-correctly)

Comment: In [pages.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/resources/pdfs/pages.pdf), there are pages of different size with different orientations. They are merged with another PDF in the [AddCover1](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/merging-pdf-documents/adding-cover-page-existing-pdf#40-addcover1.java) example. The result preserves the page size and orientation: [pages_with_cover.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/cmpfiles/merge/cmp_pages_with_cover.pdf) This proves that `PdfCopy` works as expected. If you don't agree: prove me wrong!

Comment: Add your code sample . You must be using PdfWriter or some other method. PdfCopy works for me !!

Comment: I have figured it out. Thank you Bruno. I wasn't trying to insult your work. I was just really frustrated that I was doing everything the same way as it's shown in examples but it wasn't working.

Comment: And here's my code.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/umducypr9w87unq/Merge.txt?dl=0

It turned out the problem wasn't in the code but in the pdf viewer I was using. So stupid...